# What attacks can be directed on a registration page

Tags: security, forms

I have a website registration page, and I'm trying to compile a list of what I need to do to protect it. If you know of an attack, please name it, and briefly describe it preferably with a brief description of its solution. All helpful answers/comments receive an up vote.

Here's what I have in mind so far: (and adding what others are suggesting. Phew, adding other input turned out to be lots of work, but please keep them coming, I'll continue adding here)

- SQL injections: from user input date. Solution: prepared statements.
- [AviD] "Stored Procedures also provide additional benefits (above prepared statements), such as the ability of least privilege on the DB"

  - Good point, please explain. I thought stored procedures were THE SAME as prepared statements. What I mean those statements were you bindParam the variables. Are they different?
- Not hashing the password before entering into db. Solution: hash passwords.
- [AviD] "re Hashing, the password needs a salt (random value added to the password before hashing), to prevent Rainbow Table attacks and same-password attacks."
- "the salt used should be different for each user."

  - Good point, I have a question about this: I know salt should be random but also unique. How do we establish the unique part to counter against the same-password attack? I've been reading on this, but didn't get a clear answer on it yet.
- [Inshallah] "if you use a long salt, like 16 chars for SHA-256 ($5$) then you don't really need to verify its uniqueness"
- [Inshallah] "Actually, I think it doesn't really matter whether or not there are some conflicts. The salt is only for prevention of table lookups, so even a 2 char salt will be a (small) gain, even if there are conflicts. We are not talking about a cryptographic nonce here that absolutely mustn't repeat. But I'm not a cryptanalyst"

  - Good point, but does anyone have disclaimers on this point?
- Dos attacks?! (I'm guessing this applies to registration forms too)
- [Pascal Thivent] "Use HTTPs when submitting sensible data like a password." "for man-in-the-middle attacks, provided that adequate cipher suites are used "

  - What are the "adequate cipher suites" being referred to here?
- [Koosha] "Use HTTPs or encrypt passwords before submition with MD5 and Javascript in clientside."

  - I don't agree to MD5 and don't like encrypting on client-side, makes no sense at all to me. but other input welcome.
- [Dan Atkinson] Exclude certain usernames to prevent clashes with existing pages that have the same name (see original post for full answer and explanation)
- [Koosha] "limit allowed characters for username.for example alphabet and numbers, dash(-) and dot(.)"

  - Please explain exactly why?
- [Stu42] "Use Captcha so that a bot cannot automatically create multiple accounts"
- [AviD] "There are better solutions than captcha, but for a low-value site it can be good enough."

  - @AviD, please mention an example?
- [rasputin] "use e-mail verification"
- [Andrew and epochwolf] xss attacks

  - Although I don't agree with Andrew and epochwolf to simply filter < and > or to convert < to &tl; and > to >. Most opinions suggest a library like HTMLpurifier. Any input on this?

Comment: This is very much a community wiki sort of question, as it's pretty hard to nail down the 'right answer'. Since it isn't, I think you should consider possibly adding the ideas of others to your question, so as to provide a quick point of reference to others.

Comment: re SQL Injection, do not suffice with prepared statements by themselves, you also must perform proper input validation. Stored Procedures also provide additional benefits (above prepared statements), such as the ability of least privilege on the DB.

Comment: re Hashing, the password needs a salt (random value added to the password before hashing), to prevent Rainbow Table attacks and same-password attacks.

Comment: Also, the salt used should be different for each user.

Comment: AviD, Good point, please explain Stored Procedures vs. prepared statements. I thought they were THE SAME. What I'm referring to is those statements where you bindParam the input variables. Are stored procedures different from prepared statements?

Comment: Peter Boughton, very good point. I have a question about this: I know salt should be random but also unique. How do we establish the unique part to counter against the same-password attack? I've been reading on this, but didn't get a clear answer on it yet.

Comment: @Chris, if you use a long salt, like 16 chars for SHA-256 ($5$) then you don't really need to verify its uniqueness :-).

Comment: @Inshallah, Very good point. Can you please explain why? Why doesn't 16 bytes of SHA-256 not require verification of uniqueness?

Comment: The salt is from [a-zA-Z0-9./] so: (26+26+10+2)^16 = 79228162514264337593543950336

Comment: Actually, I think it doesn't really matter whether or not there are some conflicts. The salt is only for prevention of table lookups, so even a 2 char salt will be a (small) gain, even if there are conflicts. We are not talking about a cryptographic nonce here that absolutely mustn't repeat. But I'm not a cryptanalyst...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use HTTPS, i.e. a combination of HTTP and SSL to provide encryption and secure identification of the server when submitting sensitive data like a password. *The main idea of HTTPS is to create a secure channel over an insecure network. This ensures reasonable protection from eavesdroppers and man-in-the-middle attacks, provided that adequate cipher suites are used and that the server certificate is verified and trusted.*

Comment: Ok, +1. By HTTPS you mean the SSL certificate, right? And what attack would that be? I'm guessing man-in-the-middle?

Comment: Thanks for the update, what do you mean by "adequate cipher suites" though? What are you referring to exactly? I thought the SSL certificate being signed (not self-signed) should be enough? Hmmm?!

Answer (score 4):

Use [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net) or [asirra](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/asirra/) to avoid automatic submission. That should stop the bots and script kiddies.

To stop hordes of humans from submitting spam (via mechanical turk or anything like that), log each attempt in memcached and as soon as you reach a maximum submissions from the same IP in a given period of time, block that IP for a few minutes (or hours, days, whatever...).

Comment: +1 Good point, what is a good number before the block, because according to my knowledge, AOL users are bundled into a few IPs (correct me if I'm wrong), and also, how about those in the same company? They're under the same IP too.

Answer (score 3):

You should use e-mail verification

and addition to Koosha's answer :
if you let usernames including such chars "#&?/" and create user pages like this site.com/user?me&you/ it may be serious problem in browsers. Please think it in url address bar of browsers.

Comment: Because free e-mail accounts are really hard to get?

Comment: @jrockway A few of companies block registration from major free email providers such as Yahoo, Gmail and MSN, but obviously this won't deter most folks. What it does offer is the ability to definitely link that email address to that user. This way, if the user got involved in any illegal activity on the site, then the email provider could be pursued through the courts for the IP addresses of that user, so that the ISP and police could identify them.

Comment: @Dan Atkinson, which of course leads to another good point: log the IP address.

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer of your own. :)

Comment: @jrockway it leads spammers to give up creating a lot of user accounts. It will be time consuming for spammers and cause giving up.

Comment: I don't get it, are you in favor of or against blocking the free email providers such as Yahoo, Gmail and MSN?! My point is many people don't have anything but those.

Comment: @Chris I think jrockway meant that users can get temporary e-mail address from e-mail address providers like 10minutemail.com and use it for e-mail verification.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should use a salt when hashing the passwords.

Comment: I suppose things like using third party providers like OpenId would negate this though?

Comment: +1 Good point, but why OpenId negates? I don't know much about OpenId. I'm guessing with OpenId, we don't save the passwords in our own db, right? or wrong?

Comment: Just hashing the password is not enough, @eWolf is right that you need a salt in there.

Answer (score 2):

Use Captcha so that a bot cannot automatically create multiple accounts

Comment: There are better solutions than captcha, but for a low-value site it can be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

If the routes on your website are set in a particular way (ie, going by the username, rather than their id), then having a username like 'admin' could cause problems. You should probably have an exclude list of possible usernames.

This caused problems in the past with MySpace, and people having usernames like login, and then decorating their page with a phishing form.

**Edit:**

As has been mentioned in the comments by [AviD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10080/avid) and [Peter Boughton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9360/peter-boughton), it is also a way of misleading users. Let's say that a user has the username 'admin'. Then, in their user information page (assuming that they each get one that is available to all, like SO), they have some link in their about section that says like

> For more information, visit our dev
>   blog at mysite.cn/loginpage

Someone maybe sees, 'mysite' in the url, but doesn't really look at the TLD, which would be China (sorry China!), rather than the .com TLD your site is hosted on. So they click through, assuming it's alright (they came from the admin user page after all), and this site looks identical to yours but has a login page. So you 're-enter' your details, but nothing happens. Or it redirects you elsewhere.

This is often the tactic of bank scammers who wish to target customers, inviting them to go to their website to 're-enter a banking password'.

This is just one more form of a type of security known as '[Social Engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security))'.

Comment: +1 Good point. Can you please elaborate why admin would cause a problem. I'm guessing because a page could exist called www.site.com/admin/ but what's the connection?

Comment: Well, if you have routes where the user accounts are higher in the ordering than your admin section, then, with a user called 'admin', the site.com/admin/ section will become their user page. It could then be possible for people to user their pages to phish login details for example.

Comment: Good explanation +1, although in my case, I'm not giving them their pages on the site.

Comment: This could also be an issue if there is any type of social interaction, as one user can be misled by the other users username...

Comment: Not just custom pages - for example, if users can message others then preventing names like "admin" might help prevent scammers from looking official.

Comment: @AviD & @Peter, Yes. This would be a form of a social engineering attack.

Comment: I have expanded my answer to cover more information about social engineering, and the act of manipulating unsuspecting users into performing actions that they mistakenly believe to be safe via the use of 'bad' usernames.

Answer (score 1):

Filter user's data removing '<', '>' - simply html tags. If someone can view user's profile there are possible XSS attacks through data.

Comment: or just convert < to &tl; and > to &gt;

Comment: Chris, don't filter it - use your server-side language's escape functions on all user-provided data.

Comment: filter as much as you want, but its more important to encode the output - using context-sensitive encoding, not just HTML encoding. If you're on ASP.NET, use MS' Anti-XSS framework.

Comment: I don't know about the filtering/escapring for xss. I thought the agreed upon approach for xss was to whitelist (not blacklisting) i.e. allow not disallow. And I thought that a well-built library like HTMLpurifier was the advised way over cranking out your own regexes cleanups. No? Please verify/clarify. It's kind of easier too with a library :)

Comment: If you need to allow users to post HTML, you want something like HTMLpurifier to parse the HTML and provide a safe HTML output.
But if users are just entering text that will be displayed, you only need to escape the HTML.
If user-provided text will be output in JavaScript, you want JS escaping (which differs to HTML escaping); similarly with URLs and URL escaping, and so on.

Comment: @Peter Boughton To clarify, you mean for example, if registration page asks for their website for display as link, that's HTML, then I need HTMLpurifier. Correct? Can you give me an example of when "user-provided text will be output in JavaScript"? I can't think when we could need this?!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, if page has to display a link you just have to create <a href="$user_link">$user_link</a>, correct?

About JavaScript example, let we have quite simple php script:
<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>alert("<? echo $user_message; ?>");</script></head><body></body><html>

In case of this script hacker may set $user_message to *** ");alert("Possible XSS Attack*** (without * symbols) and script will execute additional JS.

So ' and " characters are critical for escaping or removing from string.

Comment: About using 3rd party libraries. I think it's good idea, because it may not contain simple bugs(I mean filtering), which hackers can use for attack. But on other side, it may contain bugs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use HTTPS
2. Use Captcha.
3. Limit allowed characters for username in server side. for example alphabet and numbers, dash(-) and dot(.).

PS. Clientside encryption is not a secure way. but if you can't use HTTPs, clientside encryption is better than nothing.

Limiting characters, Its a simple way to protect your software from injections(SQL/XSS).

Comment: I wouldn't go md5 though and maybe not client-side. Any comments on this?

Comment: Security *must* be done server-side. Client-side is entirely untrustable. If you're using HTTPS then there's no benefit from client-side hashing, since the whole data is encrypted anyway.

Comment: Also, limiting username characters is not security, it's mostly just convention/laziness.

Comment: @Chris, you're right. Don't try to roll your own crypto, use standard HTTPS, and THEN hash on the server. Oh, and dont be using MD5 for hashing anyway - SHA-256 and up, together with salt.

Comment: SSL can be an inconvenience if you don't have a root CA signed certificate; some browsers make the user jump through hoops to get the untrusted certificate accepted. Client side hashing of passwords is a really good idea if you decide to go without SSL because your site doesn't really need the security, since it will keep an eavesdropper from taking the password and trying it out an other sites that do use and benefit from SSL encryption+authentication.

Comment: There is Javascript::SHA1 on the CPAN, which provides HMAC and SHA1 javascript functions. I guess you could HMAC the password with a salt and then do some rounds of SHA1, although I'm not sure how many rounds the browser can do in pure javascript :-)